# How do I get the Character Code (Unicode) of a compound glyph from a font file?

Tags: unicode, fonts, multilingual, glyph, pdftotext

This is my first experience working with fonts so please bear with the jargon.

**What I am doing:**
I have to extract text from PDFs containing multilingual characters (Gujarati, in this context), for which I am using Python's PDFMiner.

**Where am I stuck:**
PDFMiner does a great job in extracting most of the characters, however, for each character that it cannot extract, it gives me a CID of that character. (The font file used in PDF is [Shruti.ttf](http://www.fonts101.com/download/56888/Shruti/56A4601B62B85768479C3560BFEC38BE))

For instance: for text પર્િસિદ્ધની તારીખ, it gives, પર્િસિ(cid:263)ની તારીખ. Here દ્ધ is missing, whose CID is 263 and glyph name in the font file is .notdef#134

I extracted all the tables from Shruti.ttf file using Python's TTX/FontTools to check the character on index 263. Apparently, દ્ધ is that compound glyph, and the simple glyphs, it is comprised of, are not mentioned in 'glyf' table, rather its contour is mentioned there..

```
<TTGlyph name=".notdef#134" xMin="11" yMin="-76" xMax="1285" yMax="1352">
  <contour>
    <pt x="844" y="515" on="0"/>
    <pt x="898" y="579" on="1"/>
    <pt x="843" y="624" on="0"/>
    <pt x="843" y="691" on="1"/>
    <pt x="843" y="745" on="0"/>
    <pt x="924" y="828" on="0"/>
    <pt x="977" y="828" on="1"/>
    <pt x="1034" y="828" on="0"/>
    <pt x="1125" y="746" on="0"/>
    <pt x="1125" y="690" on="1"/>
    <pt x="1125" y="594" on="0"/>
    <pt x="1061" y="521" on="1"/>
    <pt x="1285" y="79" on="1"/>
    <pt x="1171" y="0" on="1"/>
    <pt x="1014" y="289" on="0"/>
    <pt x="951" y="422" on="1"/>
    <pt x="951" y="226" on="0"/>
    <pt x="850" y="84" on="1"/>
    <pt x="737" y="-76" on="0"/>
    <pt x="548" y="-76" on="1"/>
    <pt x="423" y="-76" on="0"/>
    <pt x="338" y="2" on="1"/>
    <pt x="249" y="82" on="0"/>
    <pt x="249" y="206" on="1"/>
    <pt x="11" y="306" on="0"/>
    <pt x="11" y="655" on="1"/>
    <pt x="143" y="655" on="1"/>
    <pt x="140" y="325" on="0"/>
    <pt x="331" y="325" on="1"/>
    <pt x="376" y="325" on="0"/>
    <pt x="389" y="378" on="1"/>
    <pt x="500" y="311" on="1"/>
    <pt x="465" y="233" on="0"/>
    <pt x="385" y="206" on="1"/>
    <pt x="385" y="136" on="0"/>
    <pt x="435" y="95" on="1"/>
    <pt x="480" y="58" on="0"/>
    <pt x="552" y="58" on="1"/>
    <pt x="668" y="58" on="0"/>
    <pt x="743" y="157" on="1"/>
    <pt x="811" y="247" on="0"/>
    <pt x="813" y="367" on="1"/>
    <pt x="599" y="356" on="0"/>
    <pt x="445" y="463" on="1"/>
    <pt x="276" y="581" on="0"/>
    <pt x="276" y="790" on="1"/>
    <pt x="276" y="988" on="0"/>
    <pt x="404" y="1065" on="1"/>
    <pt x="425" y="1078" on="0"/>
    <pt x="640" y="1142" on="1"/>
    <pt x="768" y="1180" on="0"/>
    <pt x="768" y="1282" on="1"/>
    <pt x="768" y="1352" on="1"/>
    <pt x="929" y="1352" on="1"/>
    <pt x="929" y="1280" on="1"/>
    <pt x="929" y="1107" on="0"/>
    <pt x="802" y="1048" on="1"/>
    <pt x="684" y="1014" on="0"/>
    <pt x="566" y="980" on="1"/>
    <pt x="439" y="930" on="0"/>
    <pt x="439" y="779" on="1"/>
    <pt x="439" y="649" on="0"/>
    <pt x="526" y="579" on="1"/>
    <pt x="605" y="515" on="0"/>
    <pt x="738" y="515" on="1"/>
  </contour>
  <instructions><assembly>
      NPUSHB[ ]  /* 135 values pushed */
      71 62 1 153 59 1 104 59 1 107 46 155 46 2 89 39 1 118 27 134 27 150 27 3 118
      18 1 57 14 73 14 2 25 12 57 12 73 12 3 52 4 53 13 153 12 1 12 9 30 26
      0 31 32 31 48 31 64 31 160 31 5 31 31 33 41 16 11 9 1 15 15 47 3 63 3
      2 3 9 66 26 16 25 33 16 0 23 16 23 32 23 160 23 4 23 23 0 25 16 25 32
      25 160 25 4 25 60 4 15 45 31 45 47 45 3 45 15 41 64 58 5 49 31 33 30 26
      28 5 23 33 33 37 1 11 26 6
      PUSHW[ ]  /* 1 value pushed */
      -64
      PUSHB[ ]  /* 4 values pushed */
      15 18 72 6
      PUSHW[ ]  /* 1 value pushed */
      -64
      NPUSHB[ ]  /* 24 values pushed */
      9 12 72 49 6 26 26 6 49 3 52 64 5 41 41 37 52 0 19 5 37 12 13 2
      SVTCA[0]
      MIAP[1]
      SHP[1]
      MDRP[10100]
      MIRP[01101]
      MIAP[1]
      SRP2[ ]
      IP[ ]
      MDAP[1]
      MIRP[01101]
      SRP1[ ]
      SLOOP[ ]
      IP[ ]
      MDAP[1]
      MDAP[1]
      MDAP[1]
      CALL[ ]
      CALL[ ]
      SRP1[ ]
      IP[ ]
      IP[ ]
      SRP2[ ]
      IP[ ]
      MDAP[1]
      MDRP[00000]
      MIRP[01101]
      SRP1[ ]
      IP[ ]
      SRP1[ ]
      IP[ ]
      SRP0[ ]
      MIRP[01101]
      SRP1[ ]
      SRP2[ ]
      IP[ ]
      SVTCA[1]
      MDAP[1]
      DELTAP1[ ]
      MIRP[01101]
      MDRP[01110]
      DELTAP1[ ]
      IP[ ]
      MDAP[1]
      DELTAP1[ ]
      MIRP[01101]
      SRP0[ ]
      MIRP[01101]
      SRP0[ ]
      MDRP[10110]
      MDRP[01101]
      DELTAP1[ ]
      IP[ ]
      MDAP[1]
      IP[ ]
      SRP2[ ]
      IP[ ]
      MIRP[01101]
      SRP1[ ]
      IP[ ]
      MDAP[1]
      DELTAP1[ ]
      SRP2[ ]
      IP[ ]
      SRP0[ ]
      MDRP[00110]
      DELTAP1[ ]
      SHP[0]
      MDRP[10100]
      MIRP[01101]
      IUP[1]
      IUP[0]
      DELTAP1[ ]
      DELTAP1[ ]
      DELTAP1[ ]
      DELTAP1[ ]
      DELTAP1[ ]
      DELTAP1[ ]
      DELTAP1[ ]
      DELTAP1[ ]
      DELTAP1[ ]
    </assembly></instructions>
</TTGlyph>
```

I need to know, first of all, if my approach is right or is there a better way to achieve this, secondly, given a compound glyph CID how do I get Unicode of its constituent glyphs.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you got anything in the GSUB table?

Comment: Hey bobince, one of my other colleagues has cracked this problem via some other approach, will share it soon here. Thanks.

Comment: Atif, can you share the solution? I'm facing a similar problem.

Comment: Hey pnj! Sorry I totally missed seeing your message. Are you still stuck?